# Proguard while Butterknife library and other warnings

Tags: java, android, proguard, butterknife

My Activities , Fragments ,Services and BroadcastReceivers
I want to implement a ProGuard taken to the safety of the classroom.
Error I get when Proguard.
What should I write into the file? -> proguard-android.txt ve proguard-rules.pro

I'd written into the grade.

```
  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

--

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubNavasmdcMaterialDesign14Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeKeyboardsurferAndroidWidgetCrouton185Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:proguardRelease
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find superclass or interface com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find superclass or interface com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Filer
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced field 'javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv' in program class butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Messager
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Filer
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Messager
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.Filer
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator$AnimatorListener
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarIndeterminateDeterminate$1$1: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.Slider: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.Slider$Indicator: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper
Warning:com.gc.materialdesign.views.Switch$Ball: can't find referenced class com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator
Warning:there were 262 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
:app:proguardRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.296 secs
Information:1 error
Information:172 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grade file and file as a solution `Proguard-Rules.pro` I updated as follows.
Needless to *ProGuard-android.txt* file.

Gradle:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

**`proguard-rules.pro`** file edited:

```
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**

-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }

-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}

-dontwarn butterknife.Views$InjectViewProcessor

-dontwarn com.gc.materialdesign.views.**
```

Comment: When I use the rules from this answer all the class names from all the packages are kept. None are obfuscated. I think this line is the culprit `-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}` What worked for me are the rules from this link https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/blob/master/libraries/proguard-butterknife-7.pro Which are the same rules from belphegor's answer

Answer (score 4):

Offical answer from jakewharton himself : http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: Using only these rules does not work well with view injections, for that the rules provided by Ercan PINAR has to be used.

Comment: @belphegor I can't see any proguard related information in reference link, can you please update your reference link?

Answer (score 0):

[**`proguard-rules`**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/proguard-rules.txt) for [**`butterknife:8.8.1`**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

```
 # Retain generated class which implement Unbinder.
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }

# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
```

Comment: Note that I am talking about. Thank you.

Comment: @ErcanPINAR Edited. Sorry for too late.