# ButterKnife 5.1.1 Proguard Error

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard, butterknife

I am developing an Android application and I am using `ButterKnife` library in my application. Now I need to proguard and unfortunatly, butterknife generated lot of errors. I tried lot of solutions from internet including the ButterKnife Github itself, but no good.  I am using `ButterKnife 5.1.1` and below is the error I get.

```
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced field 'javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv' in program class butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeKind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic$Kind
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.PackageElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.Diagnostic
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Elements
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.util.Types
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.tools.JavaFileObject
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.ArrayType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeVariable
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.ExecutableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.DeclaredType
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.Element
Warning:butterknife.internal.ButterKnifeProcessor: can't find referenced class javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement
```

I have added all known rules I can find into the 'proguard-rules.pro' file, please check the below for its content.

```
# Retain generated class which implement Unbinder.
-keep public class * implements butterknife.Unbinder { public <init>(**, android.view.View); }

# Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
# is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinding.
-keep class butterknife.*
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proguard while Butterknife library and other warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192874/proguard-while-butterknife-library-and-other-warnings)

Comment: @Nilabja- will it work for current version of butter knife asked here i.e. 5.1.1

Comment: Why do you still use that old version?

Answer (score 0):

For Butter Knife use the 8.8.1 version.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
```